# What is this weird thing when i'm trying to merge the head with the body on a sculpt and how do i fix it?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

i'm new to blender and sculpting in general and well as you can see i don't know how to merge the head mesh with the body mesh [image]

but i found a way to do it with the boolean modifier but when i use it this happens[image]

i don't know how to fix this or if i'm doing it wrong or is there another way to do it. ALL answers all welcome ! (Feedback,and tips too)

Comment: Make sure that your body has both its natural material + the same material as its boolean object and vice versa, it might help. Or remove boolean modifier, and manually place your head object into the body and press CTRL + J

Answer (score 1):

That weird thing is basically the second object you're boolean with overlapping the boolean result. When you use the boolean modifier on an object, this object becomes the result of the boolean operation. But the second object you use in that operation is still around in the scene, overlapping with the first. It's easiest to see if you turn on Random Color Shading:

[image: random color]

Now you should be able to see the boolean result overlapped with the second one:

[image: overlap]

To fix this, you need to hide the boolean target. One way of doing this in an elegant fashion is to use Blender 2.80 collections:

[image: collections]

Suzanne is the object that has the boolean on it. Sphere is the object I join with. I put the sphere under a new collection which I called **HideMe**. Now, I exclude it from the View Layer using the checkbox in front of the collection:

[image: hide me]

And as a result, the boolean object is not overlapping any longer:

[image: result]

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.81 has a new remesh function for object data. The remesh function is a very nice feature for attaching two objects. remesh click end
Select the two objects you want to paste and paste ctrl + j two objects and click object data >> remesh> voxel remesh

[image: voxel remesh]